# Resizing images gives tuple error

Tags: python

I'm trying to resize an image using Pillow and after looking around, a lot of people used the resize function as such

```
        image = Image.open(path_list[pair * 2])
        image = np.asarray(image).astype(np.float64)
        print("before resize is{}".format(image))
        im2 = image.resize((105, 105), Image.NEAREST)
```

However, I'm getting an error at Image.Nearest saying that

> TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Do you have the arguments switched? `.resize(a, new_shape)`

Comment: At that point in your code, `image` is a numpy array, not a Pillow image - so numpy's definition of the `.resize()` method applies, and its parameters aren't quite the same.

Answer (score 2):

As said by @jasonharper:
Your are calling the numpy method with some arguments you would use for the opencv method.
The `Image.NEAREST` argument doesn't fit in the numpy method.

Methods documentations:

**Numpy resize method:**
ndarray.resize(new_shape, refcheck=True)
new_shape : tuple of ints, or n ints
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html

**OpenCV resize function:**
Python: cv2.resize(src, dsize[, dst[, fx[, fy[, interpolation]]]]) → dst
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html